# android memory leak detection

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-leaks

The ADT eclipse plugin will report memory leaks when I run the android application (when it has leaks in it). How does the VM (or the plugin) detect memory leaks at run-time? What is the detection algorithm behind this? Also, is the detection enabled in the production environment?

Comment: What gave you that idea? There is no "memory leak detection". That would be awesome :)

Comment: You can see from logcat something like "your application is leaking" and the associated stacktrace. I guess it might not catch all the necessary leaks, but for some, it actually can.

Comment: But that's an exception. And it's probably not related to memory leaks. Can you provide such a stacktrace for clarification? Haven't seen this. However the system/garbage collector can not detect memory leaks because the GC can not know whether references cause a leak because it can not know that the referenced object should be released. That is not possible. Only the developer can know that

Comment: See this http://publicstaticdroidmain.com/2012/01/avoiding-android-memory-leaks-part-1/

Comment: That is not a detection of a memory leak. Every view needs a context to "live". In your given example that context is destroyed so you get an exception (after oriantation change a new dialog is created that references the newly created activity). Also the conclusion of this article is not true. The "window leak" does not lead to a memory leak of the activity

Comment: You can simply test this. Reference your activity via a static WeakReference in another class. Before you cause the exception set the WeakReference. Then change oriantation (this will cause the exception) and check the WeakReference. The "old" activity referenced by your WeakReference will be null (maybe you have to call System.gc() before checking in case the GC did not run yet). In the end there is no memory leak detection because there can't be one as described in the comment above

Comment: In addition: after orientation change the old "activity" isn't referenced by anything (root of GC) and also the Dialog isn't referenced by anything. And it does not matter that the dialog has a reference to the activity or vice versa. Both of them are not referenced so they are free for garbage collection

Comment: I think you are right. I will summarize a bit here, and correct me if I'm wrong: the reported "leak" is not memory leak, and it is reported because the view no longer has a valid context to "live".

Comment: Exactly. You probaly already read the article about memory leaks [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/avoiding-memory-leaks.html). If you are more interested to that topic I would advise you the Google I/O presentation about [memory management](http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/memory-management-for-android-apps.html). It also covers the topic about memory leaks (a simple example and tools how you can find/determine memory leaks)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers! I'll definitely check them out :)

Comment: That "avoiding memory leaks" link was dead. Is this the same one? http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2009/01/avoiding-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no detection for memory leaks handled by the system. The explaination is in the comments of the question